# Помогите, пожалуйста, определить тип придаточного

Tags: синтаксис

*В холле было много людей. Посему он там не задержался, **а прошёл прямо в салон**.*

Если я правильно понимаю, *Посему он там не задержался* - это придаточное причины. 
*а прошёл прямо в салон* - тоже к нему относится или нет?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Придаточного здесь нет, мы имеем **аналог сложного предложения (БСП), разделенного на два простых предложения (прием парцелляции), связанные причинно-следственными отношениями:** В холле было много людей, посему (=поэтому) он там не задержался, а прошёл прямо в салон.

Второе предложение является простым, осложненным однородными сказуемыми: Посему он там **не задержался, а прошёл** прямо в салон. Наречие "посему" используется в качестве структурного элемента для обозначения причинно-следственной связи с первым предложением.

**Примечания**

1) ПОСЕМУ, нареч. Устар. Поэтому.

2) **Парцелляция** — конструкция экспрессивного синтаксиса, представляющая собой намеренное расчленение связанного интонационно и на письме текста на несколько пунктуационно самостоятельных отрезков.

Comment: Sibylla Вы súper!!! Спасибо Вам за помощь!!! На этом форуме была user Vera, она понимала, что я иностранец и объясняла как и Вы до точности... Теперь Вы мне ооочень помогаете! : ) еще раз большое спасибо!!!

Comment: oops, я девочка, тогда иностранка : )

Comment: БСП? Но ведь здесь сразу два союза. Или я вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Серж, а откуда два союза: (1) посему (поэтому) - наречие, считается структурным элементом (дополнительным, а не основным  средством связи) в БСП, (2) союз А связывает однородные сказуемые.